# load progress bar smoothly and within certain time

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a multi group progress bar that loads from left to right smoothly but it takes around 5 secs to load.

How can i update it to load smoothly from left to right and in 3 secs?

The group bar could have 6 or more groups and should load in 3 secs

Here the link to working code

https://codepen.io/Nick1212/pen/WOVLaB?editors=1100

html:

```
<div>
  <h1 class="u-pb--lg text-bold">Grouped ProgressBar Component Examples</h1>
  <div class="space">
    <div> Example: User earning all the points</div>
    <div class="well-ProgressGroup">
      <!-- react-text: 94 --> 
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <div class="well-background--concept1 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 50%; animation-delay: 1s; z-index: -1; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept2 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 75%; animation-delay: 2s; z-index: -2; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept3 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 100%; animation-delay: 3s; z-index: -3; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept4 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 250%; animation-delay: 4s; z-index: -4; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept5 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 300%; animation-delay: 5s; z-index: -5; height: 50px;"></div>
      <!-- react-text: 101 -->
      <!-- /react-text --> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.well-ProgressGroup {
  display: flex;
  background: #d3d4d5;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes loadbar {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.well-ProgressGroup--progress {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: loadbar 1s linear forwards; 
/*   -webkit-animation: loadbar 1s forwards; */
  opacity: 0;
  background: blue;
}

.well-ProgressGroup--progress:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
} 

.well-background--concept1 {
  background: tomato;
}

.well-background--concept2 {
  background: blue;
}

.well-background--concept3 {
  background: purple;
}

.well-background--concept4 {
  background: red;
}

.well-background--concept5 {
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: try decreasing the animation time from 1sec to 0.5sec something.. `animation: loadbar 0.5s linear forwards; `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your `.well-ProgressGroup--progress` divs has an animation delay inline style in the HTML, update these in increments of `3s / 5 = 0.6s` so `0, 0.6s, 1.2s, 1.8s, 2.4s`. Then in your CSS adjust the  `animation: loadbar 1s linear forwards;` within `.well-ProgressGroup--progress` to `animation: loadbar 0.6s linear forwards;`

The first change is so that your bars fill one after the other with no gaps. The second is the speed at which each bar fills. See [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZNxBK?editors=1100)

Comment: Thanks AlexGriffis, i tried to update it your way and its working but i also have to update the animation for number of groups so passing it as an inline property but its not working while it works in css. do you know why? https://codepen.io/Nick1212/pen/WOVLaB?editors=1100

Comment: `animation` is a shorthand that includes `animation-delay` so if you need to do it inline and to account for the number of groups being passed, use just `animation` like this: `animation: 0.5s linear 1s forwards loadbar;` The first number there is the speed, the second number is the delay. Assuming you are setting the style programatically; set the speed to `3s / n` and the the delay to `i * 3s / n` where n is the number of elements and i is the index in the array of elements. [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayzYxR?editors=1100)

Comment: Tried it no luck. but if i understand correctly its calling loadbar which is in CSS and not inline. could that be the problem?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make the link to the [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayzYxR) clear. Is it working here as expected? And [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) is the order for the `animation` tag.

Comment: There's some issue on your pen link. it wont load

Comment: Thanks a million Alex. You saved me. thats working. marking as answer and also voting for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Update your `animation-delay` and `animation-duration` so that all 5 animations will take 3s:

```css
.well-ProgressGroup {
  display: flex;
  background: #d3d4d5;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes loadbar {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.well-ProgressGroup--progress {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: loadbar 0.5s linear forwards; 
  opacity: 0;
  background: blue;
}

.well-ProgressGroup--progress:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
} 

.well-background--concept1 {
  background: tomato;
}

.well-background--concept2 {
  background: blue;
}

.well-background--concept3 {
  background: purple;
}

.well-background--concept4 {
  background: red;
}

.well-background--concept5 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="u-pb--lg text-bold">Grouped ProgressBar Component Examples</h1>
  <div class="space">
    <div> Example: User earning all the points</div>
    <div class="well-ProgressGroup">
      <!-- react-text: 94 --> 
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <div class="well-background--concept1 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 50%; animation-delay: 0.5s; z-index: -1; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept2 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 75%; animation-delay: 1s; z-index: -2; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept3 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 100%; animation-delay: 1.5s; z-index: -3; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept4 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 250%; animation-delay: 2s; z-index: -4; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept5 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 300%; animation-delay: 2.5s; z-index: -5; height: 50px;"></div>
      <!-- react-text: 101 -->
      <!-- /react-text --> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @fen1x i tried to update it and passing inline property also but its not working.  The thing it could be any number of groups so need to change animation too. https://codepen.io/Nick1212/pen/WOVLaB?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

you can use milliseconds instead of seconds on the `animation-delay` property to slow down the animation. And you also need to change the CSS animation as mentioned by Alex

```css
.well-ProgressGroup {
  display: flex;
  background: #d3d4d5;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes loadbar {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.well-ProgressGroup--progress {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: loadbar 0.6s linear forwards; 
/*   -webkit-animation: loadbar 1s forwards; */
  opacity: 0;
  background: blue;
}

.well-ProgressGroup--progress:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
} 

.well-background--concept1 {
  background: tomato;
}

.well-background--concept2 {
  background: blue;
}

.well-background--concept3 {
  background: purple;
}

.well-background--concept4 {
  background: red;
}

.well-background--concept5 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="u-pb--lg text-bold">Grouped ProgressBar Component Examples</h1>
  <div class="space">
    <div> Example: User earning all the points</div>
    <div class="well-ProgressGroup">
      <!-- react-text: 94 --> 
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <div class="well-background--concept1 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 50%; animation-delay: 600ms; z-index: -1; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept2 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 75%; animation-delay: 1200ms; z-index: -2; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept3 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 100%; animation-delay: 1800ms; z-index: -3; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept4 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 250%; animation-delay: 2400ms; z-index: -4; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept5 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 300%; animation-delay: 3000ms; z-index: -5; height: 50px;"></div>
      <!-- react-text: 101 -->
      <!-- /react-text --> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```